# Xamarin forms: hiding blue line from selected tab with a CustomTabRenderer for android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I made a customrenderer for showing images in the tabs for the Android platform.
Now i'd like to know how i can remove the bottom line that shows which tab is selected.
Also, where can i get info about creating custom renderers? i looked on youtube but the example with the rounded corners doesn't show much...

```
namespace Plopsa.Android
{
public class CustomTabRenderer: TabbedRenderer 
{
    private Activity _activity;

    protected override void OnModelChanged(VisualElement oldModel, VisualElement newModel)
    {
        base.OnModelChanged(oldModel, newModel);

        _activity = this.Context as Activity;
    }

    // May put this code in a different method - was just for testing
    public override void OnWindowFocusChanged(bool hasWindowFocus)
    {   
        // Here the magic happens:  get your ActionBar and select the tab you want to add an image
        ActionBar actionBar = _activity.ActionBar;

        if (actionBar.TabCount > 0)
        {
            ActionBar.Tab tabOne = actionBar.GetTabAt(0);
            tabOne.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon_tab1);

            ActionBar.Tab tabTwo = actionBar.GetTabAt(1);
            tabTwo.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.icon_tab2);

            ActionBar.Tab tabThree = actionBar.GetTabAt(2);
            tabThree.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon_tab3);

            ActionBar.Tab tabFour = actionBar.GetTabAt(3);
            tabFour.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon_tab4);

        }
        base.OnWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
    }
}
```

Comment: same problem...could you do it?

Comment: ActionBar.Tab is obsolete when using API level 23 in Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result  by setting the Tabbar.axml class 'android:tabIndicatorColor' to the same value as the 'android:background'.

Below is the code showing the desired result with a tab indicator matching the tab background color. This is all contained in the Tabbar.axml file. You can register the tabs in the MainActivitiy.cs.

**Tabbar.axml**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabText"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/primaryOrange"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/primaryOrange"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />`

**MainActivity.cs**

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            LoadApplication(new App());

        }
```

**Example Result**

[image]